# strange *ngIf behavior in Angular

Tags: angular

In my Angular 7.2.8 app, when I add a `*ngIf` inside a `div` or other tags, the browser would generate a

> TypeError: Unable to get property 'active' of undefined or null
>   reference

When the directive is removed, then everything is fine. My workaround is to use `[ngStyle]` to bind the style to the component's variable. Has anyone seen this behavior before?  Thanks.

```html
<div class="flex-start">
  <div *ngIf="showEditArea" class="flex-column" [ngStyle]="{'display': quickLinkStyle}">
```

Comment: can you please share .ts file or specifically the value of variable `showEditArea `.

Comment: Are you trying to access the `active` property anywhere in your component code?

Comment: I think the error is inside of the ` <div *ngIf="showEditArea" class="flex-column" [ngStyle]="{'display': quickLinkStyle}">` then when  you get showEditArea in true the error triggered  because you are trying to do something like  `object.active` and object is undefined

Comment: No. I don't have any code for getting or setting object.active.